# Trying to create wine .desktop shortcut on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, wine, .desktop

The code that made the .desktop works is

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=BioEdit
Exec=wine /home/user/.wine/drive_c/BioEdit/BioEdit.exe
Icon=/usr/share/icons/BioEdit.jpg
```

If i open it from the /usr/share/applications/, it opens but with wine icon. If i favorite that icon, close and open again, it shows a lot of errors. Is it possible to make it appear on the favorite bar with the bioedit icon and make it work?